# How to select specific columns of multi-column join in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

We are testing the possibility to implement SQLAlchemy to handle our database work. In some instances I need to join a database to a clone of itself (with potentially different data, of course).

An example of the SQL I need to replicate is as follows:

```
SELECT lt.name, lt.date, lt.type
FROM dbA.dbo.TableName as lt
LEFT JOIN dbB.dbo.TableName as rt
    ON lt.name = rt.name
    AND lt.date = rt.date
WHERE rt.type is NULL
```

So far I have tried using the `join` object but I can't get it to not spit the entire join out. I have also tried various `.join()` methods based on the tutorial here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html and I keep getting an AttributeError: "mapper" or not what I'm looking for.

The issues I'm running into is that I need to not only join on multiple fields, but I can't have any foreign key relationships built into the objects or tables.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=and_#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kay's like I think I figured out the solution.

It looks like it can be solved by:

```
session.query(dbA_TableName).outerjoin(
   dbB_TableName,
   and_(dbA_TableName.name == dbB_TableName.name",
   dbA_TableName.date == dbB_TableName.date")
).filter("dbB_TableName.type is NULL")`
```